# Django update model entry using form fails

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to update a model entry using a form. the problem is that instead of updating the entry it creates a new entry.

```
def edit(request, c_id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(C, id=int(c_id))

    if request.POST:
        form = CForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('/a/b', c_id)
    else:
        form = CForm(instance=instance)

        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = form
        args['c_id'] = c_id

        return render_to_response('a/b.html', args)
```

HTML code:

```
<form action="/a/edit/{{ c_id }}/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
            {% if field.help_text %}
                <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

CForm class code

```
class CForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = C
        fields = ['name', 'code']
```

Comment: Please update your question with the html you're using to render the form.

Comment: @Soviut i've updated it

Comment: @Alasdair i've added the CForm class now

Comment: I think you might be hiding the problem by using made up variables like `CForm` - I don't think the code you have posted would create new instances. The only other thing I can think of is that the post request is being handled by the create view instead of the edit view. You haven't posted your URL patterns, so I can't tell whether that's the case. You could add some printing/logging to make sure that the correct view is being called.

Comment: @Alasdair you were right. a wrong view was called. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You're checking the request for a `POST` method incorrectly. [`request.POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) isn't a boolean, it contains a dictionary of post variables and is always going to have the CSRF token in it so it will always be "truthy". What you need is [`request.method`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method).

Instead of:

```
if request.POST:
```

Replace it with:

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. it just adds another entry in the database